# Facebook PathPicker does not work with ZSH

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

I am trying to use [Facebook PathPicker](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker) with ZSH.

When I try to run a command on a selection I get this error:

```
> git status -uno | fpp

/root/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/root/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 13: `for config_file ($ZSH/lib/*.zsh); do'
/root/.zshrc: line 123: unsetopt: command not found
/etc/bash_completion.d/git: line 126: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/etc/bash_completion.d/git: line 126: ` done < <(git config -z --get-regexp '^(svn-remote\..*\.url|bash\.showupstream)$' 2>/dev/null | tr '\0\n' '\n ')'
/etc/bash_completion.d/grub: line 417: `_grub_mkpasswd-pbkdf2': not a valid identifier
```

I am currently using version 0.6 of fpp:

```
> fpp --version

fpp version 0.6.0
```

Any idea about how can I fix this?

### Edit:

Here is the output of `/bin/bash -x "$(whence fpp)"`

```
> /bin/bash -x "$(whence fpp)"
+ SOURCE=/usr/local/bin/fpp
+ '[' -h /usr/local/bin/fpp ']'
+++ dirname /usr/local/bin/fpp
++ cd -P /usr/local/bin
++ pwd
+ BASEDIR=/usr/local/bin
++ readlink /usr/local/bin/fpp
+ SOURCE=/usr/local/PathPicker/fpp
+ [[ /usr/local/PathPicker/fpp != /* ]]
+ '[' -h /usr/local/PathPicker/fpp ']'
+++ dirname /usr/local/PathPicker/fpp
++ cd -P /usr/local/PathPicker
++ pwd
+ BASEDIR=/usr/local/PathPicker
+ PYTHONCMD=python
+ doProgram
+ python /usr/local/PathPicker/src/processInput.py
Using old result...
+ exec
+ python /usr/local/PathPicker/src/choose.py
+ sh /root/.fpp/.fpp.sh
```

This is the content of `/root/.fpp/.fpp.sh`:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
if [ -f ~/.zshrc ]; then
  source ~/.zshrc
fi
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
  source ~/.bash_profile
fi
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  source ~/.bash_aliases
fi
echo "executing command:"
echo "ls '/root/myfile'"
ls '/root/myfile'
```

I am not an expert, but I suppose that this file is created on the fly.
Here is where bash is sourcing the `~/.zshrc`

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sourcing your Zsh init scripts from your Bash env, and that is not permitted (since the syntaxes are not compatible). Check you `BASH_ENV` environment variable.

Also, why are you running as root?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I'll check the two files and see if there is any reference to the scripts of Zsh.
Do you know if I can set fpp to ignore completely bash and use Zsh instead?

Comment: @Muffo No you can't, because [`fpp`'s landing script](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker/blob/2210077af7e36aa6c76ee51512c946a32fc9060d/fpp) is written in Bash, despite `fpp` being mostly a Python project. The reason seems to be whoever wrote it in the first place didn't know how to redirect stdin in Python.

Comment: I actually suggested to the maintainers even before they open sourced the project that this could be pure Python (thus avoiding the shell init problems altogether), and wrote an example script for them, but they decided in the end that it's not worth rewriting. More info in [Homebrew/homebrew#39324](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/39324) and [facebook/PathPicker#1](https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker/issues/1).

Comment: Anyway, sourcing Zsh init scripts in Bash init scripts is wrong, so you don't want to do that.

Comment: I have checked my `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` but I didn't see any trace of the zsh scripts. I have also opened a ticked on github to track the issues, although it might be related to the configuration of my machine as you suggested

Comment: Looking at the error messages it's clear as day that `oh-my-zsh.sh` is being sourced/executed by `bash`. If you could execute `/bin/bash -x "$(whence fpp)"` in Zsh and post the output, then I might be able to trace down where it's sourced.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I was confusing the various bash init scripts. The init scripts shouldn't be sourced when you execute the scripts. What you should check is your `BASH_ENV` environment variable. The comment above still applies: run `/bin/bash -x "$(whence fpp)"` and post output. Feel free to pipe stuff into it.

Comment: I think that we are on the right track. I have edited the question to keep things more clear as the comments are not great to paste the output from the terminal...

Comment: @Muffo Okay, that's a bug. Fix is here: https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker/pull/138